# Get Drop Down Menu, PHP SQL HTML

Tags: variables, get

I am a student and also working in my university. I am not studying computer science.
I mainly do support stuff, but now I should take care of our internship database.

Task: Create a drop down menu from a town which a student choses, then show all internships in this town.

I have an existing SQL database, can create a drop down menu from it, but have NO idea how I can use the selected value. A submit button would be fine, any solution which works is fine.

How can I put the chosen value from drop down menu to a PHP variable?

```
<?php
$dbanfrage = "SELECT DISTINCT Stadt FROM $tabelle WHERE Land = 'China' OR Land = 'Taiwan' OR Land = 'VR China' ORDER BY STADT ";
$result = mysql_db_query ($dbname, $dbanfrage, $dbverbindung);

if (!$result) 
{
    $message  = 'Ungültige Abfrage: ' . mysql_error() . "\n";
    $message .= 'Gesamte Abfrage: ' . $dbanfrage;
    die($message);
}

echo "<select>"; 
echo "<option>Stadt ausw&auml;hlen</option>";                   // printing the list box select command

while($nt = mysql_fetch_array($result))                     //Array or records stored in $nt
{   
    echo "<option value = $nt[id]>$nt[Stadt]</option>";     /* Option values are added by looping through the array */
} 
echo "</select>";                                           // Closing of list box  
mysql_close ($dbverbindung);
?>
```

Comment: Create a form and place your drop down on that. On submitting you will get the drop-down value in your PHP page. But before that specify a name in your SELECT tag.

Answer (score 0):

Just suggesting how you can do it --

```
<select name="country" id="country" onChange="showState();" >
<option value="">Select Country</option>
<option value="1">India</option>
<option value="2">Nepal</option>
</select>
```

Your Script--

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function showState( )
{
var value = document.getElementById('country').value;
var url = '<?php echo base_url ?>showstate.php';
$.ajax({
type: "GET",
url: url,
data:{'country':value},
success:function(results)
{   
    $('#div_state').html(results);
}
});
}
</script>
```

Your `showstate.php` php page --

```
//INCLUDE CONNECTION file to for db query
$type = $_GET['country'];

//Your DB QUERIES
```

This will load the content in your `#div_state` div. You can also use Jquery For this..i think this will help you :) an d let me know if you have any query.

Comment: @user1451086 you can always have a better way to do this thing..its just an intro to what you asked :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<select name="name">
   <option value="select">select</option>
  <?php 
    $dbanfragee=mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT Stadt FROM $tabelle WHERE Land = 'China' OR Land = 'Taiwan' OR Land = 'VR China' ORDER BY STADT ");
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($$dbanfrage)){?>
        <option value="<?=$row['id']?>"><?=$row['stadt']?></option>
    <?php }?>
</select>
```